# Google OAuth Local Redirect URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise

I've found a couple topics similar to this*, but none feature an answer that is working for me currently.

I've set up my local rails server using /etc/hosts to run at "http://zen.example.com" and have added the following entries to my Google redirect URI's list:

```
zen.example.com
zen.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
*.example.com/*
```

(This is using devise + omniauth and the google oauth2 strategy).  Now that I've done this I follow my oauth link that takes me here:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=596705606035.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fzen.example.com%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgoogle_oauth2%2Fcallback&state=ba07e128aea49aeb2443711336d5af6cc711a341f609a48a&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force
```

I end up with the following error from Google:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://zen.example.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a registered redirect URI
```

[image: See screenshot]

Reference:
* [Why is Google Oauth returning `invalid redirect_urI` in my Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215863/why-is-google-oauth-returning-invalid-redirect-uri-in-my-rails-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by:

1) Creating a new client key using the *old* google console.

2) Ensuring it was using http not https

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`omniauth-google-apps`](https://github.com/T145/omniauth-google-apps)! It always helped me in a situation like this.

Comment: How does this vary compared with the main google oauth?

Comment: It's an updated and better version that can help when interacting w/ more recent rubies, such as Rails 4.