# Laravel 5.1 social Authentication is not working properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Recently i am working on laravel 5.1 framework and trying to make user login by Social Authentication like facebook login .. 
i followed this tutorial from youtube  [Laravel 5.1 Socialite Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZWJCoXN6Us&index=24&list=PLpRNkmPv_dKHoicxrsB8QVMYjeKoEiCWK)

but get this Exception

`InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 191:`

```
in AbstractProvider.php line 191
```

at AbstractProvider->user() in SocialAuthController.php line 61
at SocialAuthController->github_Callback()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(SocialAuthController), 'github_Callback'), array()) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('github_Callback', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164

Here is my code

```
// facebook Sociolite for routing 
Route::get('/auth/facebook', 'Auth\SocialAuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('callback_facebook', 'Auth\SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback');

// AuthController

 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Http\Requests;

 use App\User;
 use Validator;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

 use Socialite;
 use Auth;
 use redirect;


 class AuthController extends Controller
 {
     class SocialAuthController extends Controller{   
     // For Facebook
     public function redirectToProvider(){

        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
     }
     public function handleProviderCallback(){
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $data = ['name'=>$user->name, 'email'=>$user->email,    'password'=>$user->token];
        $userDB = User::where('email',$user->email)->first();

        if (!is_null($userDB)){
            Auth::login($userDB);
        }
        else{
            Auth::login($this->create($data));
        }
        return redirect('/pages/profile');
    }
  }
}

    config\service.php
    'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => '513845902100524',
        'client_secret' => '135699237e16cd3a50d2cbfec3a5e58c',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/callback_facebook',
    ],
```

Comment: there was a cookie issue on my side. i solved it using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31738836/1090395

Answer (score 0):

You can get detail documentation from laravel [official site](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication).  Socialite tutorial  [here](http://www.codeanchor.net/blog/complete-laravel-socialite-tutorial/).

Comment: thnx Ishahriyar for u'r reply after followed this tutorial http://www.codeanchor.net/blog/complete-laravel-socialite-tutorial/

i got another Exception