# Laravel Auth::login() doesn't persist after change domain in session

Tags: php, session, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

previously before i change the domian in session.php,my Auth::login() is working fine and it will persist the cookie so they dont need to login again. When some of my friend told me that when they click login (from facebook), it will somehow return InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php.

I google around knew there maybe some issue cause by the cookie, and the solution is changing the domain in the session.php from null to my domain (example myapps.com).

After i've change to the myapps.com, invalidstateException no longer occurs but it wont persist my login. After a 6 - 12 hours, it required me to login again.

Below is my code ( i believe my code is correct just after i've change the session and the login wont persist anymore).

```
$UserLogin = User::where('facebook_id', '=', $user->getId())->first();
Auth::login($UserLogin, true);
```

Comment: Ask them to clean their cookies and try to login again

Comment: already did, but still wont persist. even i clear and login again it wont persist. Should i change the domain in session.php to null or to myapps.com ? If it's null it will persist, just sometime it will cause  InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php.

Comment: "After a 6 - 12 hours, it required me to login again."? So the session is persisting for up to 6 hours? What have you set the `lifetime` and
    `expire_on_close` settings to?

Answer (score 7):

The core problem is that your browser stores **two cookies** from **multiple domains with the same cookie name** called `laravel_session`; when you make a request, both cookies with the same name are sent to the server.

In your `config/session.php`:

```
//change this
'cookie' => 'laravel_session'

//and this
'domain' => 'my_domain'
```

By changing the name of the `cookie` and `domain`, you'll get around the problem by the storing new cookies under a new name.

Comment: MAN, You are a LIVE SAVER!

Comment: thanks, I would like to add that you should not specify ports
SESSION_DOMAIN = 127.0.0.1: 8000
right
SESSION_DOMAIN = 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It's because old cookies stored in your browser are interfering with the new domain that you have set.

So to get your login working again clear your browser cookies after setting up domain in configuration file