# Laravel Socialite in "stateless" mode -- security implications?

Tags: laravel, security, oauth, laravel-socialite

[Laravel Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) has a "stateless" mode which disables storing anything to session. From a read of the source code it doesn't do anything different instead -- it just doesn't store or retrieve these values.

As part of this, it [assumes](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/c4e4337e5b70149fdbefbb95b2c9e93d0749c413/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php#L234) for example that the OAuth state is always valid.

Checking this is one of the things which the [Twitter sign-in documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing), for example, tells us to do.

So I'm wondering what sort of security implications using the stateless mode of Socialite could have.

If it's anything serious, what sort of workarounds would there be, for an application running as a stateless API? I could store things in its Redis store, but I'm not sure how I'd tie any bit of information to the current user. By reimplementing what Socialite does I could for example store the state in the cache, keyed by some hash of the user's IP and browser fingerprint. But this seems very messy.

Comment: Check out this video at 30:19: https://vimeo.com/138774235, and the slides from it here: https://www.slideshare.net/alvarosanchezmariscal/stateless-authentication-with-oauth-2-and-jwt-javazone-2015

Stateless API's aren't any more insecure that ones with state checks, just different measures taken

Comment: @tech1000, I already understand and use JWT once a user is signed in. That's not what this question is about. This question is about the sign-in flow provided by Laravel Socialite. The user is not yet authorized and so does not yet have an access token during this procedure.

Comment: State checking as provided by Laravel does not affect the security of OAuth authorization itself in any way. The user is still redirected to the 3rd party for sign in (via HTTPS), and receives a secure and validated AccessToken + RefreshToken with which to access the resource server.

You mention: << The user is not yet authorized and so does not yet have an access token during this procedure. >>

State checking always happens after authorization, as the random string is stuck into the session only after OAuth has succeeded, it's an after measure, not an essential one.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Socialite generates the random string as part of the "redirect" call and passes it to the OAuth provider. It's then checked against what the OAuth provider calls back with. So this is affecting the log-in flow in some way.

Comment: Furthermore, the Twitter documentation I pointed out instructs the developer to hold on to the `oauth_token` received in the response to the first call to the provider, and check this against the `oauth_token` given in the callback step. Without state how is this check taking place? If this isn't a security issue, why is Twitter telling us to check it?

Comment: It doesn't affect the login flow, it's just an additional check. 
An analogy:  Imagine you're travelling, and want to cross the border. The border agent will ask you for your passport (OAuth AccessToken). This is the prime security mechanism. You can also show your driver's license (state check) as a secondary confirmation; however, you can never enter with just a license, your passport must be valid. You can bother all you want with the license, but if the passport is easy to forge, that's the security hole. In other words, state adds some security, but it's not essential nor mandatory.

Comment: Using state checks makes your system more robust, but not using them doesn't make it implicitly insecure. An attacker would still need to forge the random high entropy AccessToken to gain entry. Since these are time-expired, they would have to do an aweful lot of computation rather quick.
Overall I would trust the stateless OAuth, as much as I trust using an API KEY based REST API. Which in the end is basically same as a user+password mechanism:  it all depends on the entropy of your secrets.

Comment: Can you comment on what I said about the Twitter OAuth documentation?

Comment: As far as I can tell the speciific Socialite driver for Twitter (not the other services) is only available in OAuth 1, which is different from OAuth 2.

Looking at the code specifically for Twitter, it seems a session storage is not optional?

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/One/AbstractProvider.php#L110

There is no Stateless option for Twitter, so you may be going around in circles for nothing if that is the provider you intend to use. Notice the documentation you linked is for OAuth 1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, that does throw a spanner in the works. It seems there's [a separate version](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/issues/43) where other people are also having problems with stateless Twitter auth.

Comment: The error is actually quite silly: `Call to undefined method ...stateless()"

Because the abstract provider in Oauth 1 does not have this method.

Please see: https://twittercommunity.com/t/getting-started-with-oauth-2-0/2338

<< We only support one specific type of OAuth 2, for application-only authentication (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth). User-based authentication has to use OAuth 1.0a. >>

Comment: Yes, I saw that and drew the same conclusions, before commenting on the issue thread I linked.

Answer (score 0):

This answer from @iandayman shows what could go wrong without OAuth `state` parameter in a login flow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35988614