# Laravel Socialite : Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am new to Laravel Socialite and I am getting this error while redirecting back from Social media login

> Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException in/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php:209**

Even I have tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738836/4428431  But still I am facing the same error.

Here the code for Socialite controller

```
// Redirect to Social provider for login
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

// Handling get request from social provider
public function handleProviderCallback($provider, Request $request)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
}
```

Actually the code was worked in the beginning but it stopped working after i have redirected non-www to www.
Here the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L] 

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    #RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you try using `$user = Socialite::with($provider)->user();` ? This may be a problem with cookies as well, so take a look at them in `config/session.php` ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue and fixed by adding `->stateless()`

```
$user = Socialite::driver( $provider )->stateless()->user();
```

Comment: Be aware, this opens up the possibility for an attacker to inercept the callback, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35988614/6883749

Answer (score 0):

use session guard or stateless

1.session guard

you can see guard in config/auth.php (drivers and providers)

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('login/{provider}', 'SocialController@redirect');
    Route::get('login/{provider}/callback','SocialController@Callback');
    Route::get('login/{provider}/callback','SocialController@Callback');
});
```

here web is guard

2.stateless use (->stateless)

```
$user = Socialite::driver( $provider )->stateless()->user();
```

Note:
Stateless authentication is not available for the Twitter driver, which uses OAuth 1.0 for authentication.

Comment: It does not work for me, using Laravel 10.10, PHP 8.1.2