# Laravel Socialite Providers Manager hasInvalidState

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

am using login with MIcrosoft Graph (Socialite Providers) but when I call

```
$user = Socialite::with('graph')->user();
```

It appear this exception:

```
exception 'Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException' in vendor\socialiteproviders\manager\src\OAuth2\AbstractProvider.php:32
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738836/5892849

Comment: I already tried that but the error is still there.