# InvalidStateException once the user signin to the application

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, okta-api

I am using Okta socialite to integrate and authentication. Once of my customer is facing an issue that it showsan 'InvalidStateException'. But I could not recreate the issue. The redirect function is provided below and the screenshot of the error.

```
class OktaController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('okta')->redirect();
    }
...
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Socialite: InvalidStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660847/laravel-socialite-invalidstateexception)

Comment: Thank you for the response and the link. The stateless() may help to fix the issue. But how can I recreate the issue? I tried almost all the way such as cleared the cookies, session everything is working fine. Can you help me to find a way to recreate it and ensure to fix it?