# Laravel with Socialize(fb) say: InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 150:

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I try to implement https://github.com/laravel/socialite at my Laravel 5.1 project.

So as I read at documentation I write:
at services.php

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' =>  env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT'),
],
```

also at app.php I add:

```
    Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
```

and aliases:

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
```

Now at AuthController I add:

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

 public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
 //notice we are not doing any validation, you should do it

    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    // stroing data to our use table and logging them in
    $data = [
        'name' => $user->getName(),
        'email' => $user->getEmail()
    ];

    Auth::login(User::firstOrCreate($data));

    //after login redirecting to home page
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

and route.php:

```
Route::get('/social/login/redirect/{provider}', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider', 'as' => 'social.login']);
Route::get('/social/login/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

But NOW when I try to go at http://www.domain.com/social/login/facebook I get:
[image]

What is wrong? WHere I make error? Hw to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**
MY .env file is:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID=<app_id>
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET=<app_secret>
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT=http://www.domain.com/social/login/redirect/facebook
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629287/laravel-5-geting-invalidstateexception-in-abstractprovider-php

Comment: Did you fix it? I have the same problem.