# Socialite in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm trying Socialite with laravel 5.1 and I always got this error during call back route

> ```
> InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 200:
> ```

and this is my code for callback route

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider) {
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
}
```

additional information about issue
I saw this error happened when I authenticated from facebook only , when I disable this code in AbstractProvider.php line 200

```
throw new InvalidStateException;
```

Show new error

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 geting InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629287/laravel-5-geting-invalidstateexception-in-abstractprovider-php)

Comment: I did test all answer and still error show to me :(