# Laravel Socialite: InvalidStateException (sometimes)

Tags: php, laravel-socialite

*some* of the users on my site are experiencing 
a `Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException`.  I've taken the steps outlined in the replies to [Laravel Socialite: InvalidStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660847/laravel-socialite-invalidstateexception) and have not been able to resolve the issue.  Only a small percentage of users seem to be experiencing this.

I have 2 fpm/nginx docker containers sitting behind an HAProxy load balancer.

Comment: try the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629287/laravel-5-geting-invalidstateexception-in-abstractprovider-php

Comment: @KareemEssawy Commenting that out is a huge security issue

Comment: probably you can try in a dev environment what is causing the problem, is it the login function or something else , also do you use Socialite for  OAuth authentication with Facebook ?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660847/laravel-socialite-invalidstateexception

Comment: Just delete all sessions and let people sign-in again.

Comment: @markus These folks are logging in for the first time.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be an invalid state issue in [socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) package that is already resolved in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660847/laravel-socialite-invalidstateexception#31738836).

Some of your users are accessing your website with a different url (https://www.example.com or https://example.com) hence causing the mismatching "state" in the sessions.

If you are on Larvel 5.3 and above... add a `SESSION_DOMAIN=http://example.com` in the `.env` file

For other versions go to your `config/session.php` file, and add your domain. `'domain' => 'www.example.com'`

To apply changes immediately. Run `'php artisan cache:clear'` and `'composer dump-autoload'` Hopefully this should resolve the issue.

Comment: what do you do for localhost?

Comment: I suppose simply write localhost or if you have a port do 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: @ConnorLeech For localhost stage, google will ignore it, this solution is only for production stages

Answer (score 5):

I bet you that the issue is appearing because of the load balancer. Here's my theory:

1. **Sticky sessions**: if your load balancer hasn't sticky session properly configured, it's possible for some users to start a new session on server 1 and on a following request it ends on server 2 which maybe is throwing the `Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException`
2. **Request timeout**: I'm not sure of this but, maybe your session lifetime isn't enough to complete some process that also throws the `Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException`

Maybe if you change the laravel session storage to a decentralized database instead of the default text file configuration, the exception gets solved.

Comment: The session is persisted in an external `redis` instance which both `nginx/fpm` containers share for session storage.  Wouldn't that eliminate the **Sticky Sessions** theory?

Comment: Then yes, that's not a sticky sessions issue. Is the authentication via API? Reading about socialite with redis found this [socialite stateless authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/socialite#stateless-authentication) maybe this help.

Comment: So... maybe I'm misunderstanding stateless.  After the user logs in, I use my token to get more data from their API.  Would it be suitable for me to use stateless in this scenario?

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong? I mean, is your back end separated from your front end? Does your app authenticate users with an oauth  or similar?

Comment: It randomly stopped showing up a week ago.  Though I can confirm I haven't touched this process in 10+ days.  So I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

In your production env file just add SESSION_DOMAIN=http://example.com to be picked up by your config/session.php. For local development, you won't need that.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
Socialite::driver('google')->user();
```

to this code

```
Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
```

any social (any social login like facebook github etc)

Comment: What does `any social` at the bottom of your answer mean?