# Non-public domains not allowed

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to log in to the Google Analytics API using OAuth 2.0, but it only works on localhost, not on my production server, which returns the following error :

> **Error: invalid_request**
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Non-public domains not allowed: http://extranet2/dev/analytics/oauth2callback.php

The problem is that the server is not accessible from outside of my company and has a non-public domain name.

Google doesn't seem to allow non-public domains for the redirect_uri parameter, is there any way to bypass this ?

Comment: Do you have access to the DNS? [It appears you can use a public domain and redirect to the correct IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215863/why-is-google-oauth-returning-invalid-redirect-uri-in-my-rails-app)