# Error when accessing Google OAuth from Docker container : device_id and device_name are required for private IP

Tags: docker, flask, oauth, google-oauth, flask-oauthlib

I have a dockerized flask app running from a docker-machine with IP `192.168.99.100` that is trying to access Google OAuth. However, I am getting the following error:

> Error: invalid_request
>
> device_id and device_name are required for private IP:
>   http://192.168.99.100:8001/login/authorized

I tried the suggestions from [Why is Google Oauth returning `invalid redirect_urI` in my Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215863/why-is-google-oauth-returning-invalid-redirect-uri-in-my-rails-app) and edited my `/etc/hosts`

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
192.168.99.100 chatbot appiumchatbot.com
```

and updated OAuth details in the google console.

Google OAuth details:

```
Authorized JavaScript origins: http://appiumchatbot.com
Authorized redirect URIs: http://appiumchatbot.com:8001
```

## update

I even tried the `xip` and `nip` methods suggested in [Error: invalid_request device_id and device_name are required for private IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736168/error-invalid-request-device-id-and-device-name-are-required-for-private-ip)

I am still getting the exact same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: invalid\_request device\_id and device\_name are required for private IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736168/error-invalid-request-device-id-and-device-name-are-required-for-private-ip)

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks! I tried that too..getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

if you have a trouble with accessing to your web with xip.io, you should check about somethings below

1. google redirect uri : http://192.168.99.100.xip.io:8001/login/authorized
2. for testing on a local host, access to 192.168.99.100.xip.io:8001 instead of 192.168.99.100:8001